# Access (menu) items that are not shown in Firefox New menu button

Tags: windows-7, firefox, gui

As all know, the new firefox has a new interface(a nice one,at least to me), it has got a three-lined button to open the menu as shown in the picture below:

[image: Menu button]

When the **Customise** button is clicked , it shows all the menu options, I select some of them which are used often. But there are other menu items that may be of use very rarely and I haven't placed them in the menu box(or whatever you call it). But, when I want to use them, I have open **Customisation** and add that to the menu in order to use it.
Is there any other way to access the menu items that are not added to the menu?
**UPDATE:** To clarify what are the options I am looking for, see the image below(items those are in the red rectangle).
[image]

Comment: No other way as far as I know.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry to hear that.

Comment: Could you add what options are you looking for? If you mean items in the old top menu, you can press the Alt key.

Comment: @user3169 not those items, but the items which you can see when you open the **Customise** window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons inside the red border can be added to the Firefox toolbar, or to its main menu (the box on the right that appears when you click the three-line 'hamburger' button). I put the buttons I use most frequently on the toolbar, and I put the ones I use less often on the main menu. Features I never use I leave in the area where you have the red border.

In other words: click the hamburger button, click **Customize**, drag the buttons you want to be on the hamburger menu, from the area you've outlined in red to the area below the hamburger button, then click **Exit Customize**.

Comment: What about **Pocket, Share This Page, Hello, Tab Groups etc** that aren't added to the _hamburger_  bnutton?

Comment: I like **Hamburger** (button, of course)

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional details.

Comment: I do not want to put them in the menu and clutter it. Where I can find the Pocket, Hello etc(They are not shown in the menu bar).

Comment: They are in the customizer until you add them to the toolbar or the menu. Where do you want them to be? If you want to use a feature, it has to be in the UI somewhere, so add it. Alternatively, you can find everything in the classic menu: just press **Alt** to see it.

Comment: But, I cant find Pocket and Hello in the classic menu?

Comment: You're just going to have to add Pocket and Hello to one of the toolbars or the hamburger menu.